# Can I stop Apple News from prioritising Covid news in my newsfeed all the time?

Tags: news.app, apple-news

Every single time I open Apple News, it shows Covid-related news at the top. Every single time I have to scroll past all of them to start reading topics I’m interested in.

Doesn’t look like Apple News have learned anything about my newsfeed preferences after months of using it. I keep ignoring those “top news” and scrolling past them every time, and it keeps showing them to me as “top news” again and again.

Is there a way to hide covid-related topics from my personal newsfeed once and for all? It is super annoying, and seems like I can’t get rid of this noise at all, which makes the News app unusable for me.